# How I do to the driver to install/upgrade automaticly? And manually?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, upgrade, automation

I there am much time before, I thought the Ubuntu don't upgraded the driver (Nvidia) automatically, or at least, to upgraded, I thought to had to reboot the Ubuntu, I resolved to install on Nvidia website or on terminal, I regretted to installing manually the driver (Nvidia), because the system alters to manual the installations, How do I change to the automatic installation? Case I regret to change to the automatic installation, How do I change to the manual installation? I don't have as to install all drivers manualy, because the options disappear When I turn off or reboot the PC, is very strange

Comment: I do not know how you will remove the manually installed drivers, but please backup your data before making changes to the drivers as they can be very difficult to fix.  The easiest way I know of to use the NVidia drivers would be to run the program "Additional Drivers" which will attempt to identify which drivers will work for your system.

Comment: I don't can to change the driver, because the other options don't is possible to select, and if I install the drivers, When I turn off or reboot the PC, it disappears, someone knows How to do an automatic driver installation on the terminal? Remember the driver is Nvidia, and don't AMD or intel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Graphic Interface:

Automatic Installation:

I found one solution for this problem without to execute the terminal, this is workable solutions can save you:
First made a backup before doing anything (I recommend installing TimeShift for this, because that program is more effective), second — upgrade your system on occasion, third — before to reboot the PC, reboot the driver instead reboot only the PC, because if you reboot the PC, is possible the system don't change the driver.

Manual Installation:

And How I install the driver manually? Searching by the Nvidia, AMD or Intel website, you need to know your kind GPU Nvidia, AMD, or Intel to you has for you install the correct driver.

Terminal:

Automatic Installation:

I was to search something related to the automatic installation on the terminal and I find one solution very easy and practical, open the terminal and write:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -plow unattended-upgrades
```

You should to accept and don't worry, the system go usually find one stable upgrade of driver more recent

Manual Installation:

Go to additional driver, and you will see these names:

[image]

I recommend installing of the open source driver, because the community can resolve better the bugs and problems than the close source driver. Now for example, whether I want to install the open source driver, I write on terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install driver-name (as xserver-xorg-video-nouveau, nvidia-driver-460, etc)
```

I wait to have helped, the solutions are interesting